# How To Send HTTP Request To Google API Like in Google Oauth Playground?

Tags: java, http, https, google-oauth

I tried the google oauth playground here:
https://developers.google.com/oauthplayground/

---

Step 1, I choose calendar API v3, then asked for permission -> I select my google account and clicked "allow"

Step 2, I clicked "Exchange authorization code for tokens"

Step 3, I typed "https://www.googleapis.com/calendar/v3/calendars/primary/events" (choosing to list all events that I have), then clicked "Send the request" -> the output is HTTP response containing list of my events in my primary calendar in json format

---

My question is:
Can I use the google API (especially calendar) just like this via HTTP Request-Response?

Basically I want to make the HTTP request as shown in the playground, and get the HTTP response as shown in the playground

(for example: using java socket programming like below)

```
        String httpsURL = "https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token";

        String query = "code="+("123123123123codehere"); 
        query += "&client_id="+("123123123123.apps.googleusercontent.com");
        query += "&client_secret="+("123123123123");
        query += "&redirect_uri="+("urn:ietf:wg:oauth:2.0:oob");
        query += "&grant_type="+("authorization_code");

        URL myurl = new URL(httpsURL);
        HttpsURLConnection con = (HttpsURLConnection)myurl.openConnection();
        con.setRequestMethod("POST");

        con.setRequestProperty("Content-length", String.valueOf(query.length())); 

        con.setDoOutput(true); 
        con.setDoInput(true); 

        DataOutputStream output = new DataOutputStream(con.getOutputStream());  

        output.writeBytes(query);
        output.close();
        DataInputStream input = new DataInputStream( con.getInputStream() ); 

        for( int c = input.read(); c != -1; c = input.read() ) 
        System.out.print( (char)c ); 
        input.close(); 

        System.out.println("Resp Code:"+con .getResponseCode()); 
        System.out.println("Resp Message:"+ con .getResponseMessage());
```

these code didn't work and the output is blank (why? the string httpRequest is copy pasted exactly as in the oauth playground, and the token haven't expired yet)

Also I plan to use these in php with curl, can it be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Google APIs like calendar API are just [rest APIs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Representational_state_transfer) which means that they run over HTTP GET and HTTP Post requests.

You can easily send the raw http posts and gets to google and get your responses back.

The access token you get will expire after one hour.   A refresh token will not expire and is used to get a new access token when it does expire.  I have a tutorial on [Google 3 legged oauth2 flow](https://www.daimto.com/google-3-legged-oauth2-flow/)

you might want to consider using the [Google Java client library](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/java/) though it will be easier.

Comment: why would my program above return null result? Is there something wrong? (maybe the port number is wrong, or anything else?)

Comment: I would not expect it to return null.   Even if the user has no events it would return a response https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/reference/events/list#response with nothing in the item list.  Unfortunately my java knowledge is basic but how are you reading the response?

Comment: I've read your article at https://www.daimto.com/google-3-legged-oauth2-flow/ and I'm stuck at step to obtain access token, it return 404 error

Comment: Any reason you cant use the client library?  404 means you are typing the wrong end point in.   Remember some of the calls are HTTP POST not HTTP GET

Comment: At the previous comment I said it's 404 error, now I changed it to POST (before I used GET). I have updated the question with my java code to post, now it return 400 bad request

Comment: print out "query" check what it says.   just replace the secret and post it to me.   Let me see what it looks like.  Note: it is normal for it to be this hard if your not using the client library.   It takes a while to work it out without documetnaiton.

Comment: oh, I find out myself... I have to delete the DataOutputStream.